# Is there a way to create a "stored procedure" call multi queries in single query at mongodb(mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Is there a way to create "stored procedure" in mongodb?

### For example a query to access mongodb once but actually calling more than one collections?(use mongoose to call mongodb)

I know mongodb has [serverside javascript](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/server-side-javascript/). But It's different, I don't think server side function is able to call collection.
For example if I have following example.

### 1. example one (relational collections)

```
 mycollection1.findOne({_id: id}, function(err, result1){
       mycollection2.findOne({_id: result1.id}, function(err, result2){
                 mycollection3.findOne({_id: result2.id}, function(err, result3){
                     return {};
                 });
       });
    });
```

### 2. example two(none-relational collections)

```
mycollection1.findOne({_id: id}, function(err, result1){
       mycollection2.findOne({}, function(err, result2){
                 mycollection3.findOne({}, function(err, result3){
                     var someDataToDisplayToUI = 
                          {
                           data1 : result1,
                           data2: result2,
                           data3: result3
                           };
                     return someDataToDisplayToUI;
                 });
       });
    });
```

I'm using mongoose from express.js server, currently mongoose call three times of above example. Is there a way to call once?

Answer (score 2):

`MongoDB` doesn't support queries spanning multiple `collections`. There's no way around it. You have to make multiple queries at the application level. What you are doing seems to be the way to go. That is the pitfall of non-relational database. Maybe if you need to make these calls frequently, you would be better off with a relational database or it would be good to reconsider your schemas.

MongoDb isn't relation friendly. But as you are using `mongoose`, if you have any relationships, you can have references in documents across multiple collections and use a neat option called `populate` which fetches data from other collections.

> Still mongoose will internally make two mongo queries

. This option makes defining relationships a whole lot  easier.

Check [the docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html).

Populate can't be used for more than one level at a time.

```
 mycollection1.findOne({_id: id}).populate('id',null,','<Collection2 Model Name>',function(err,result1){
     //result1.id will be your result2 in the question instead of an id
     result1.id.populate('id.id',null,'<Collection3 Model>',function(err,result){
       //result1.id.id is now your result3 in the question
     })
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this's very helpful. But I still think MongoDB should have that kind of ability. There should be some case, call none-relational collection and pass all data without access MongoDB many times. There should be lots of use case, isn't it.

Comment: @user2650480 yes. MongoDb isn't relation friendly. But as you are using mongoose, if you have any relationships, you can have references in documents across multiple collections and use a neat option called `populate` which fetches data from other collections. Still mongoose will internally make two mongo queries. This option makes defining relationships a whole lot easier.

Comment: I understand mongodb wasn't design like a traditional relational database. So mongoose probably create populate. But isn't any one want to call many collection at MongoDB server side and return to application?  I know MongoDB is faster, doesn't anyone want to use like this way? I'm just wonder...

Comment: I understand your worries, yes making multiple calls is a big disadvantage. Mongoose makes this very easy for you through populate. You have to make a design choice. If your use case is strongly relational, best avoid mongo. If most of your data is document oriented, mongo is your best best.